# Connecting to Access Database in SharePoint, from Excel VBA code also in SharePoint

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I have an Access 2007 database in SharePoint. I have an Excel macro which interacts with my Access database.

This works as long as both the Excel macro and Access database are in local folder or share drive, but I want to keep both Excel macro and database in SharePoint, and Excel should connect to the Access database.

Here is my code snippet.

```
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Sample.accdb"

'Workbook Path is https://example.com/Sites/Sample/Sample.xlsm

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection Conn.Mode = adModeReadWrite

sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
```

This gives me an error

> "Invalid File Name"

How do I connect to Access data from Excel in SharePoint?

Comment: Me too facing the same issue to connect to database which is in sharepoint. Checked many forum and links but no solid solution for this question.